# Plotting Precision-Recall curve when using cross-validation in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using cross-validation to evaluate the performance of a classifier with `scikit-learn` and I want to plot the Precision-Recall curve. I found [an example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_precision_recall.html) on scikit-learn`s website to plot the PR curve but it doesn't use cross validation for the evaluation.

How can I plot the Precision-Recall curve in scikit learn when using cross-validation?

I did the following but i'm not sure if it's the correct way to do it (psudo code):

```
for each k-fold:

   precision, recall, _ =  precision_recall_curve(y_test, probs)
   mean_precision += precision
   mean_recall += recall

mean_precision /= num_folds
mean_recall /= num_folds

plt.plot(recall, precision)
```

What do you think?

Edit:

it doesn't work because the size of `precision` and `recall` arrays are different after each fold.

anyone?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of recording the precision and recall values after each fold, store the **predictions** on the test samples after each fold. Next, *collect* all the test (i.e. out-of-bag) predictions and compute precision and recall.

```
 ## let test_samples[k] = test samples for the kth fold (list of list)
 ## let train_samples[k] = test samples for the kth fold (list of list)

 for k in range(0, k):
      model = train(parameters, train_samples[k])
      predictions_fold[k] = predict(model, test_samples[k])

 # collect predictions
 predictions_combined = [p for preds in predictions_fold for p in preds]

 ## let predictions = rearranged predictions s.t. they are in the original order

 ## use predictions and labels to compute lists of TP, FP, FN
 ## use TP, FP, FN to compute precisions and recalls for one run of k-fold cross-validation
```

Under a single, complete run of k-fold cross-validation, the predictor makes one and only one prediction for each sample. Given n samples, you should have n test predictions.

(Note: These predictions are different from training predictions, because the predictor makes the prediction for each sample without having been previously seen it.)

Unless you are using **leave-one-out cross-validation**, k-fold cross validation generally requires a random partitioning of the data. Ideally, you would do **repeated** (and **stratified**) k-fold cross validation. Combining precision-recall curves from different rounds, however, is not straight forward, since you *cannot* use simple linear interpolation between precision-recall points, unlike ROC (See [Davis and Goadrich 2006](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jdavis/davisgoadrichcamera2.pdf)).

I personally calculated **AUC-PR** using the Davis-Goadrich method for interpolation in PR space (followed by numerical integration) and compared the classifiers using the AUC-PR estimates from repeated stratified 10-fold cross validation.

For a nice plot, I showed a representative PR curve from one of the cross-validation rounds.

There are, of course, many other ways of assessing classifier performance, depending on the nature of your dataset.

For instance, if the proportion of (binary) labels in your dataset is not skewed (i.e. it is roughly 50-50), you could use the simpler ROC analysis with cross-validation:

Collect predictions from each fold and construct ROC curves (as before), collect all the TPR-FPR points (i.e. take the union of all TPR-FPR tuples), then plot the combined set of points with possible smoothing. Optionally, compute AUC-ROC using simple linear interpolation and the composite trapezoid method for numerical integration.

Comment: There any explanation on using PR instead of ROC on imbalanced data? Is ROC useless or lack of meaningful insight of model in imbalanced case, and why? Thank you for any response.

Comment: I found the relevant paper, will take time to read :http://www.autonlab.org/icml_documents/camera-ready/030_The_Relationship_Bet.pdf

Comment: ROC AUC can certainly be used for imbalanced data, in fact it is often one of the preferable metrics in imbalance even in extreme cases. It has a number of preferable statistical properties to PR. Can see David Powers answer here and refs https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/roc-vs-precision-and-recall-curves. However, in needle in the haystack type problems where we care a lot about not getting false positives in the positive fraction PR is more sensitive than ROC, although in ROC this will still be picked up by a small drop in specificity when N>>P.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently the best way to plot a Precision Recall curve for an sklearn classifier using cross-validation. Best part is, it plots the PR Curves for ALL classes, so you get multiple neat-looking curves as well

```
from scikitplot.classifiers import plot_precision_recall_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

clf = LogisticRegression()
plot_precision_recall_curve(clf, X, y)
plt.show()
```

The function automatically takes care of cross-validating the given dataset, concatenating all out of fold predictions, and calculating the PR Curves for each class + averaged PR Curve. It's a one-line function that takes care of it all for you.

[Precision Recall Curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W3TU.png)

Disclaimer: Note that this uses the [scikit-plot](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot) library, which I built.

Comment: How would we know how many fold cross-validation is being used here inside plot_precision_recall_curve() ?