# Computing average precision-recall curve when using cross-validation in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, precision-recall

I'm trying to draw average plot, using the following way:

1. Compute precision-recall curve for all folds.
2. **Compute average precision-recall curve. I don't know how to do it because dimension in different folds is different.**
3. Draw curve,that was computed in the second step.

   P.S. Solution from there [Plotting Precision-Recall curve when using cross-validation in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587759/plotting-precision-recall-curve-when-using-cross-validation-in-scikit-learn) is not suitable because if I compute average of all predictions and then compute precision-recall curve I will get AUC = 1.0. This is wrong.

I want to get something like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scores = []
for train, test in kfold:
    true, pred = clf.predict(test)
    precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(true, pred)
    scores.append((precision, recall))
precision_avg, recall_avg = compute_average(scores)
plt.plot(precision_avg, recall_avg)
```